# Build "timeline" from 2 date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, range

I've been racking my brain but can't do the following in an efficient manner:

Basically I have 3 date ranges as follows:

```
ID |  StartDate |  EndDate
-----------------------------
1  | 1905-01-01 | 1910-01-01
2  | 1920-01-01 | 1990-01-01
3  | 2010-01-01 | 2020-01-01
```

The expected result is:

```
ID |  StartDate |  EndDate
-----------------------------
1  | 1900-01-01 | 1904-12-31
2  | 1905-01-01 | 1910-01-01
3  | 1910-01-02 | 1919-12-31
4  | 1920-01-01 | 1990-01-01
5  | 1990-01-02 | 2009-12-31
6  | 2010-01-01 | 2020-01-01
7  | 2020-01-02 | 9999-12-31
```

From a given set of date ranges, build a timeline from the earliest possible date to the latest possible date.

I have built one query but it's very inefficient. It utilizes LEAD and LAG but the actual result sets are "UNION ALL"-ed one at a time. In addition it is not dynamic, it can only handle 3 date ranges at a time. I'm trying to build a dynamic one but every time i try to, I end up approaching the problem the same way. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just list out the dates and use `lead()`:

```
select row_number() over (order by dte) as id,
       dte as startDate,
       coalesce(dateadd(day, -1, lead(dte) over (order by dte)), '9999-12-31') 
from ((select startDate as dte
       from t
      ) union all
      (select endDate as dte
       from t
      )
     ) t;
```